# Search for a part of an array and get the rest of it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I've got an array called $myarray with values like these:

```
myarray = array ( 
    [0] => eat-breakfast 
    [1] => have-a-break
    [2] => dance-tonight
    [3] => sing-a-song
)
```

My goal is to search for a part of this array and get the rest of it. Here is an example:

If i submit **eat**, I would like to get **breakfast**.

If i submit **have**, I would like to get **a-break**.

I just try but I'm not sure at all how to do it...

```
$word = 'eat';
$pattern = '/'.$word.'/i';
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
   if(preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches)){
       echo $value;
   }
}
print_r($matches);
```

It displays:

```
eat-breakfastArray ( )
```

But I want something like that:

```
breakfast
```

I think I'm totally wrong, but I don't have any idea how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the word you seek is at the beginning. Try this

```
function f($myarray, $word)
{
    $len = strlen($word);
    foreach($myarray as $item)
    {
        if(substr($item, 0, $len) == $word)
            return substr($item, $len+1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

[**`stripos($word, $myarray)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php
$myarray = array ( 
    'eat-breakfast',
    'have-a-break',
    'dance-tonight',
    'sing-a-song'
) ;


function search($myarray, $word){
    foreach($myarray as $index => $value){
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false){
            echo  str_replace(array($word,'-'), "", $value);
        }
    }
}

search($myarray, 'dance');
echo "<br />";
search($myarray, 'have-a');
echo "<br />";
search($myarray, 'sing-a');
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/19827/3)

Comment: The questioner wants to only have 'breakfast' returned, when searching only the word 'eat'

Comment: No, watch his post once again, he wants `But I want something like that:

eat-breakfastArray ( ) `

Comment: @Ergo I'd appreciate if you could delete your downvote, because there's nothing wrong with my answer and is doing exactly what OP wants

Comment: @genesis it may be a typo at the end, earlier he requests to only receive the end part.  May I humbly suggest updating to `$myarray[str_replace("$word", "", array_search($word, $myarray))];` and potentially move it over a line or two?

Comment: @Whetstone it is currently wrong, because array_search returns an index, not a word. Edited, but thanks

Comment: Sorry genesis, I made a mistake in my final example. So your second solution correpond to what I was looking for.

Comment: sing gives me asong instead of a-song. I think I need to add an if statement because str_replace replace every dash.

Comment: sure, the OP edited the question- there have been edits to both the questions now, and the answer- in their original forms there was a mismatch, now there isnt so +1

Answer (score 0):

You're feeding the wrong information into preg_match, although I'd recommend using array_search()..   Check out my updated snippet:

```
$word = 'eat';
$pattern = '/'.$word.'/i';
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
   if(preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches)){
       echo $value;
   }
}
print_r($matches);
```

To get rid of that last bit, just perform a str_replace operation to replace the word with ""

Comment: I wasn't going for the feed them the answer approach, I wanted to let them know that they're feeding bad arguments into their function.  I've updated with a recommendation to use array_search(), but still feel it's proper to let the poster know what went wrong on their bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

This will both search the array (with a native function) and return the remainder of the string.

```
function returnOther($search, $array) {
    $found_key = array_search($search, $array);
    $new_string = str_replace($search . "-", "", $array[$found_key]);
    return $new_string;
}
```

Comment: Great function!  Might I suggest splitting it into a couple more lines for readability?

Comment: It seems to only return the first letter. For example: eat returns e

Comment: Sorry, I had `$search` where it should have been `$array`. Fixed.